# Getting mother board serial number without WMI and without authentication

Tags: c#, serial-number, motherboard

Is there any way to get mother board serial number without using WMI and without authentication of remote machine.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.pagetable.com/?p=27

Comment: I sure _hope_ you can't get the serial number without authentication!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not possible. You must use an local administrator account on the remote machine, so an authentication is required. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28VS.85%29.aspx).